# ios: insert into sqlite table using FMDB

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I am trying to create and insert into a table that is created on the way(dynamic table name).
I am able to create the table, but can not insert into it. I am using the code that is given below, every time I try, success = 0.

```
BOOL success =  [db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO ? (fname, lname,) VALUES
(?,?);",business.tablename,businessType.fname, businessType.lname, nil];
NSLog(@"success=%d", success);
```

I have been trying for a long time, please provide me with an example for inserting in table with table name in variable.

Comment: can i put my code of insertion table into DB using singleton class

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
NSString *insertQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ (fname, lname,) VALUES (?,?);",business.tablename];
BOOL success = [db executeUpdate:insertQuery,businessType.fname, businessType.lname, nil];
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *insertQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ (firstName, lastName,) VALUES ('James','Bond');",_tableName];
FMDatabase * userDB = [self openDB:[appDel getDBPath]];
if(userDB){

 [userDB beginTransaction];
 [userDB executeUpdate:insertQuery];
 [userDB  commit];
 [userDB close];
}
```